# Is mozFullPath in Firefox during file upload a security risk?

Tags: javascript, html, security, firefox, file-upload

I am working on a little photo app where the user selects a local file and it is pushed into a canvas with `window.URL.createObjectURL(file)` - really basic stuff. During testing I briefly dumped the contents of the File array to the console - just to make sure I was getting what I want.

I am using Firefox 31.0 (not Iceweasel) and Chrome 34.0.1847.116 (not Chromium) on Debian 7

I am calling the array like this:

```
               var file = evnt.target.files[0];
               if (file) {
                     console.log('file');
                     // other stuff
               }
```

The console.log looks like this in the Google Chrome Browser:

```
File {
  name: "image.png"
  size: 55464
  type: "image/png"
  webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

And like this in Mozilla Firefox Browser:

```
File { 
  size: 55464, 
  type: "image/png",  
  name: "image.png", 
  path: "",
  lastModifiedDate: Date 2014-09-09T13:30:30.000Z,  
  mozFullPath: "/home/server/Desktop/image.png" 
}
```

I can request:

```
console.log(evnt.target.files[0]['type')
```

and correctly receive `"image/png"` as response, however when I request:

```
console.log(evnt.target.files[0]['mozFullPath']);
```

I just get a response of: `""`

Why does this information leak through the `evnt.target.files[0]` array, but is invisible when I call it directly?

Is this information about the structure of my filesystem only being shown to my privileged console, or can it be leaked via man-in-the-middle attacks on my browser?

EDIT

In older Firefox browsers this would have worked to elevate permissions:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
```

But it does not anymore. At any rate, it is an issue when using Firefox on public Linux terminals / other people's computers because IT DOES leak file system information like directory structure and system username. Together with other exploits, this seems to me to be a dangerous threat... Or am I just overreacting?

Comment: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/File.html says, _“available only to code with UniversalFileRead privileges in chrome”_ (where “chrome” seems to mean [the part of Firefox this runs in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Chrome), not the browser named Chrome) – so maybe “UniversalFileRead” is something to investigate. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File however does not even offer any further explanation for `mozFullPath` any more it seems.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File.mozFullPath > "This article is in need of a technical review."