# How can I filter out directories from upload handler in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, file-upload, mozilla, directory-upload

**Problem**

I have following code snippet that is used to get file information during file drag and drop upload:

```
var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];

    // I need notDirectory(file) function.
    notDirectory(file).then(function(file) {
      output.innerHTML += 
           `<p>
              Name: ${file.name}</br> 
              Size: ${file.size} bytes</br> 
              Type: ${file.type}</br> 
              Modified Date: ${file.lastModifiedDate}
            </p>`;
    });
}
```

I did research and found that Firefox does not support directory uploads, but allows client to drag and drop them to drop area.

**Question**

How can I filter out directories from upload handler in Firefox?

**Update**

You can find working sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/gevorgha/exs3ta25/

Please consider that I need it to work on [the latest stable Firefox version - 
46.0.1](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) without enabling extra preferences from browser, because I don't want to ask users to enable preference to make upload work properly.

Comment: Hello, where exactly did you read that? I either don't quite understand about which part you're talking or at least for me it is working?

Comment: I want to know which files are directories. Currently I don't know how to get that info from File API.

Comment: Firefox nightly 45+ supports directory upload

Comment: @gevorg See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842425/select-drop-files-and-or-folders-to-be-parsed/

Comment: Thanks, so for nightly builds it supports directory uploads. My question would be is there any workaround for latest stable Firefox version to detect directories? Because on stable version that feature is disabled by default or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

I came up with following dirty workaround that works on [Firefox version - 46.0.1](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/)

It uses [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to check if uploaded file is directory or not.

**Code**

```html
<div id="dropArea" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 50px; text-align: center;">
    Drop your files here!
</div>

<script>
    // Get target elements.
    var dropArea = document.getElementById("dropArea");

    // To be defined.
    function notDirectory(file) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            // Can read files, but not directories.
            reader.onprogress = function(event) {
                if ('progress' === event.type) {
                    resolve(file);
                    reader.abort();
                }
            };

            // Wait for result.
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    }

    // Attach drop listener.
    dropArea.addEventListener("drop", function (event) {
        // Stop propagation.
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        // Loop files to filter out directories and print files.
        var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];

            // I need notDirectory(file) function.
            notDirectory(file).then(function(file) {
                // Print info.
                console.log({
                    name: file.name,
                    size: file.size,
                    type: file.type
                });
            });
        }
    });

    // Attach drag move listener.
    dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", function (event) {
        // Stop propagation.
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

**Related Links**

- [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
- [JavaScript Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Note, `FileReader()` constructor does not expect a parameter to be passed

Comment: Interesting approach. You could probably use `if(file.size === 0 && file.type === "" && file.name !== "")`

Comment: Dangerous, e.g. `__init__.py` file in python will match that case, because it is empty in 99% cases.

Comment: But `file.name` is not empty for directories, what will it give?

Comment: `name` should be name of directory; `mozFullPath` will provide full path to directory. Your approach is appears to return expected result as to your requirement

Comment: I was asking what for should I add `if(file.size === 0 && file.type === "" && file.name !== "")`, because I don't see case that it will exclude?

Comment: Was not able to retrieve `.mozFullPath`, though it is visible at `console`  https://jsfiddle.net/exs3ta25/29/

Comment: Found reason cannot access `.mozFullPath` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765655/is-mozfullpath-in-firefox-during-file-upload-a-security-risk#comment40292389_25765655

Comment: Yep, we need to enable privilege for it.

Answer (score 2):

> My question would be is there any workaround for latest stable Firefox
>   version to detect directories? Because on stable version that feature
>   is disabled by default or do I miss something?

Directory upload was not enabled by default at firefox 47, where tried `html`, `javascript` at stacksnippets, jsfiddle.

See [Firefox 42 for developers Interfaces/APIs/DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/42#InterfacesAPIsDOM)

> The `Directory` interface has been experimentally extended (bug
>   [1177688](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1177688)). The two members `Directory.path` and
>   `Directory.getContents` can be exposed by setting the
>   `dom.input.dirpicker` preference to `true`.

A workaround to detect folder upload could include

1. Use `<input type="file">` with `directory` and `allowdirs` attributes set, possibly including `multiple` attribute, see [Note](https://wicg.github.io/directory-upload/proposal.html#h-note6), for drag and drop or user selection on click of container;
2. Open `prefs.js` or `about:config` and set `dom.input.dirpicker` preference to `Boolean` `true`;
3. Use modified version of "Code example" for "1. File input" at [Directory Upload Demo](https://wicg.github.io/directory-upload/);
4. To check if upload is a [`Directory`](https://wicg.github.io/directory-upload/proposal.html#idl-def-directory) and not a single `File` object, use `if` with condition  `(filesAndDirs[0] && filesAndDirs[0].constructor.name === "Directory")` or `(filesAndDirs[0] instanceof Directory)` inside of `.then(function(filesAndDirectories){})` at chained to [`.getFilesAndDirectories()`](https://wicg.github.io/directory-upload/proposal.html#dom-htmlinputelement-getfilesanddirectories);
5. Substitute `<label>` element for `<div>` element as parent of `<input type="file">`. Adjust `css` of `input type="file"` to fill parent droppable container and set `opacity` to `0`; adjust `css` at parent element of `input type="file"` to display text at `:before` pseudo-element, over `input type="file"` child element.

See also [New API for directory picking and drag-and-drop](https://jwatt.org/blog/2015/09/14/directory-picking-and-drag-and-drop).

Note, approach was tried at firefox 47, where both directories and individual files were successfully uploaded.

```js
var dropArea = document.getElementById("dropArea");
var output = document.getElementById("result");
var ul = output.querySelector("ul");

function dragHandler(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  dropArea.className = "area drag";
}

function filesDroped(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  dropArea.className = "area";

  var uploadFile = function(file, path) {
    // handle file uploading
    console.log(file, path);
    var filesInfo = `<li>
                        Name: ${file.name}</br> 
                        Size: ${file.size} bytes</br> 
                        Type: ${file.type}</br> 
                        Modified Date: ${file.lastModifiedDate}
                      </li>`;
    ul.innerHTML += `${filesInfo}`;
  };

  var iterateFilesAndDirs = function(filesAndDirs, path) {
    for (var i = 0; i < filesAndDirs.length; i++) {
      if (typeof filesAndDirs[i].getFilesAndDirectories === 'function') {
        var path = filesAndDirs[i].path;

        // this recursion enables deep traversal of directories
        filesAndDirs[i].getFilesAndDirectories()
          .then(function(subFilesAndDirs) {
            // iterate through files and directories in sub-directory
            iterateFilesAndDirs(subFilesAndDirs, path);
          });
      } else {
        uploadFile(filesAndDirs[i], path);
      }
    }
  };
  if ("getFilesAndDirectories" in event.target) {
    event.target.getFilesAndDirectories()
      .then(function(filesAndDirs) {
        // if directory
        var dir = filesAndDirs;
        if (dir[0] && dir[0].constructor.name === "Directory") {
          
          console.log(dir);
          var directoryInfo = `<li>
                        Directory Name: ${dir[0].name}</br> 
                        Path: ${dir[0].path}
                      </li>`;
          ul.innerHTML += `${directoryInfo}`;
          alert("isDirectory:true");
        }
        iterateFilesAndDirs(dir, "/");
      })

  } else {
    // do webkit stuff
  }
}

dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", dragHandler);
dropArea.addEventListener("change", filesDroped);
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  width: 98%;
  height: 180px;
}

label[for="file"] {
    width: 98%;
  height: 180px;
}

.area {
  display:block;
  border: 5px dotted #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.area:after {
  display: block;
  border:none;
  white-space: pre;
  /*content: "Drop your files here!\aOr click to select files";*/
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  top: -75px;
  text-align:center;
}

.drag {
  border: 5px dotted green;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#result ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#result ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label id="dropArea" class="area">
  <input id="file" type="file" allowdirs directory webkitdirectory/>
</label>
<output id="result">
  <ul></ul>
</output>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/exs3ta25/31/

Comment: Thank you for your great input on question, however none of these works on [the latest stable firefox version - 46.0.1](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) without enabling extra settings from browser.

Comment: @gevorg Note, drag and drop was not returning expected results at firefox. Firefox provides two `<input>` fields for selection when `allowdirs` attribute is set; when file is dropped into `Choose folder...` the directory was not recursively iterated; adjusted stacksnippets and jsfiddle for user click selection on either `Choose files...` or `Choose folder...` `input`

Answer (score 1):

You can read a little about this in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files) (including Firefix). Here is a function (not made by me but I edited maybe a half of it) that detects whether drop is file or folder and shows its name, size and what type (tested in FireFox):

```
function handleDrop(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var filesInfo = "";

    var files = e.dataTransfer.files,
        folder;

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
    {
        if (!f.type && f.size % 4096 == 0)
            folder = true;
        else
            folder = false;

        filesInfo += 'Name: ' +  f.name;
        filesInfo += '<br>Size: ' +  f.size + ' bytes';
        filesInfo += '<br>Type: ' +  (folder ? 'folder ' : 'file');

        output.innerHTML = filesInfo;
    }
}
```

I hope that's what you were looking for. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, but this code will also mark as directory e.g. **LICENSE** file with 4096 bytes or any other file with unknown type and 4096 byte size. Not 100% accurate method.

Comment: Damn, it is true. Sorry about with invalid function. :/